# How to add missing dependencies in .aar format

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, aar

```
dependencies {
compile('com.mycompany.test:mycompany-test:1.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
    changing = true
}
```

My dependencies look like this in `build.gradle` file. I have a folder naming mycompany-test. How to add this dependency in my project. Also how can we create `.aar` file from existing piece of code. Tried already this link but do not work for creating `.aar` file

Please help as this part is very new to me !!

Comment: If `mycompany-test` is a module in the same project, then you can just do `compile project(":mycompany-test")`. If it's a separate project, you should start by generating the .aar file first but this is a completely separate question.

Comment: forgot to add `this link` ?

Comment: something wrong here. If it is a project in a folder you can't add in this way